# How to dispose Bitmaps created during CellFormatting

Tags: winforms, idisposable

I am using the CellFormatting event to display images based on some other result in my DataGridView.

This looks like

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
// If in correct column and row, etc...
    Bitmap bitmap = CreateBitmap();
    e.Value = bitmap;
    e.FormattingApplied = true;
}
```

Now, how would I dispose these bitmaps I create reliably?

Comment: When its sufficient to dispose the bitmaps when the form closes, then you could keep a list of bitmaps and dispose them in the virtual Dispose method of the form. It depends on how you use the form though.

Comment: Good idea!. In this case though, this is a long lived form so this approach would probably have a lot of non-disposed bitmaps for a long time.

Comment: You can only dispose them once you dispose the datagridview, or once you get new images for the datagridview cells. You can't dispose them while they are displayed in the datagridview. BTW, you can shorten your code by removing the `Bitmap bitmap = CreateBitmap()` and simply do `e.Value = CreateBitmap()`.